# GPU No Longer Working Without Monitor

Tags: graphics-card, display, gpu

I've been remotely using a pc with an integrated amd gpu for a long time, without a monitor plugged in. I temporarily used the pc with a (new) monitor plugged in, and now basic things like explorer and internet browsers will display, but not videos or even pictures without the monitor plugged in.

Is there any way to fix this? I read about dummy plugs but got the impression they don't work with integrated gpus.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: How are you remoting in? Is it with Microsoft Remote Desktop? Have you tried performing a clean re-installation of the GPU driver? What GPU is it?